# Dojo xhrGet return empty data

Tags: ajax, dojo

i´m newbie in dojo and have a problem with xhrGet, it return empty response data.

```
function test1(){
            // Using dojo.xhrGet, as very little information is being sent
            dojo.xhrGet({
                // The URL of the request
                url: 'http://www.dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/ajax/demo/get-content.php',
                // The success callback with result from server             
                load: test2,                
                // The error handler
                error: function(errorMessage) {
                    // Do nothing -- keep old content there
                    alert("Error Message: " + errorMessage);
                }
            });
        }
        function test2(result, ioArgs){
            alert(result);
            dojo.byId("tContent").innerHTML += result;
        }
```

i debuged this code and result is empty always. can anyone say me, what i doing wrong?

thanks in advance

dimi

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is because your site is at yourdomain.com, but you are trying to fetch data from dojotoolkit.org. This doesn't work because of the [same origin policy](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy&ei=i9ovTuv0CIT3mAXfmpwf&usg=AFQjCNHVFZYpkC1JSDNgda021fYJ8pRuDQ) in your browser (you cannot request a page from a different domain). Try replacing the dojotoolkit url with something from your own domain.

Comment: hi frode, i must get data from another site. i find out now that i must use "Cross-Site XHR Plugin". am i on the right way?

Comment: @user864980 Yes, you probably are. You may also want to do a search on JSONP (padded JSON). The various tricks depend on your server/service and how it presents the data.

Comment: can you give me an simple example (f.e. load any http-content), please. i found any snippets, but its not working...